# WpfToolkit Chart DependentValue Dynamically

Tags: wpf, bar-chart, toolkit

I don't know if it is possible to do but I will try.
I have a problem with following code:

```
      <charts:Chart Grid.Row="0" Height="262" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Title="Column Series Demo" 
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="360">
                <charts:ScatterSeries
DependentValueBinding= "{Binding ElementName=XAxisCb,Path=SelectedItem}"
IndependentValueBinding= "{Binding ElementName=YAxisCb,Path=SelectedItem}"
x:Name="Series" 
DataPointStyle="{StaticResource RingChartSymbolStyle}" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Patterns}"  />
            </charts:Chart>

  <ComboBox x:Name="XAxisCb"  ItemsSource="{Binding DependentNamesX}" SelectedItem="{Binding DependentNameX,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
  <ComboBox x:Name="YAxisCb" ItemsSource="{Binding InDependentNamesY}" SelectedItem="{Binding InDependentNameY,Mode=TwoWay}"/>

public class Pattern
{
  public List<IFeature> Features
        {
            get { return _features; }
            set { _features = value; }
        }
}

 public interface IFeature
    {
         string Name { get; set; }
        double Value { get; set; }
    }
```

If I have Class `Point` I just set X axis to property X and Y axis to property Y.
Now I have `Pattern` Class which contains `List<IFeature>` which means List of Properties.
How to set DependentValueBinding and IndependentValueBinding to take for example first Property from features to X (Pattern.Features[0]) and second Property to Y (Patter.Features[1] in every pattern?

For example like this:

```
 DependentValueBinding= "{Binding Features[0]}"
 IndependentValueBinding= "{Binding Features[1] }"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could use data templates although the question is somewhat unclear..

in your window's resources:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PatternsDataTemplate">
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Features}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FeaturesDataTemplate}"/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="FeaturesDataTemplate">
  <Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

then after the chart you could do something like this...

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Patterns}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PatternsDataTemplate}"/>
```

not really sure if you want a combobox within a combo box or what you're trying to do, but this should give you the gist of it if I understood enough of the question

Comment: No that's not my question. I want to set now X axis to 1st element of the features and Y axis to 2nd element of the features.

Comment: ah yes in that case the solution would be much easier

Answer (score 0):

Solution was so easy :)

```
 IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Features[0].Value}"
 DependentValueBinding="{Binding Features[1].Value}"
```

EDIT: I Thought I can get actual element by using Properties or Converter parameter but both are restricted. So it is not final solution. I Don't know how to bind Features[i] where I is UI dependent.

Comment: Honestly I'd like to help, but I spent time trying to help yesterday and it was clear I didn't understand the question.. Perhaps you could explain what you're trying to accomplish by using C# or pseudo-code to illustrate the logic of what you're trying to do..